# OpenGL on MacOSX

Tags: linux, macos, opengl

I'm writing an app that heavily uses OpenGL; either on the Mac or on Linux.

I've heard of various rumors of Apple having buggy OpenGL drivers (and a reluctance to fix them). Can anyone confirm/deny this?

If you've developed on OpenGL on both Mac and Linux, how do they compare?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at this [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Mac_OS_X_games) of Mac OS X games (which includes games like WoW and the upcoming StarCraft II) and the fact that Mac OS X itself uses OpenGL heavily for windows compositing and various eye candy makes this a highly dubious claim.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe they are buggy as such; merely poorly supported by Apple when something does actually go wrong in some way.

There are plenty of instances of things such as a low-end card from one manufacturer rendering much faster than a high-end card from another which can take a long time to get fixed if at all.